# django-sane-testing doesn't start live server

Tags: django, testing

I'd like to run Selenium tests on CI server so I need running live server before run tests. I subclass HttpTestCase, write some tests using Selenium, then I do like here http://devel.almad.net/docs/django-sane-testing/usage.html#running-tests:

```
set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings_test
set PYTHONPATH=.
nosetests myapp.tests:MyHttpTestCase --with-django
```

Seems it's creating DB, then it connects to Selenium and run FF (I see that two FF windows). But then it fails, saying it can't connect. I suppose this is because of it didn't start developer server.

Don't know where I'm wrong, seems I was doing it by instruction...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass --with-djangoliveserver to nosetests:

```
nosetests myapp.tests:MyHttpTestCase --with-django --with-djangoliveserver
```